# Lucene Index Search without stoppers

Tags: search, lucene, lucene.net

I am doing some queries over a Lucene index, right now I'm looking for latin phrases over this queries. The problem is that some of this phrases include words that i think are consider like stoppers. For example if my search term is "a contrario sensu" the result is zero but if I only search for "contrario sensu" i have over 100 coincidences.

The question is how can i do a search without this stoppers?

My code looks like this

```
public IEnumerable<TesisIndx> Search(string searchTerm)
{
        List<TesisIndx> results = new List<TesisIndx>();

        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(FSDirectory.GetDirectory(indexPath));
        QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("Rubro", analyzer);


        PhraseQuery q = new PhraseQuery();
        String[] words = searchTerm.Split(' ');

        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            q.Add(new Term("Rubro", word));
        }

        //Query query = parser.Parse(searchTerm);
        Hits hitsFound = searcher.Search(q);

        TesisIndx sampleDataFileRow = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < hitsFound.Length(); i++)
        {
            sampleDataFileRow = new TesisIndx();
            Document doc = hitsFound.Doc(i);
            sampleDataFileRow.Ius = int.Parse(doc.Get("Ius"));
            sampleDataFileRow.Rubro = doc.Get("Rubro");
            sampleDataFileRow.Texto = doc.Get("Texto");


            results.Add(sampleDataFileRow);
        }
}
```

I use a StandardAnalyzer to build the index and perform the search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a stop word. However, when it comes to phrase queries, that doesn't mean it isn't considered at all. If you try printing your query after parsing, you should see something like:

> Rubro:"? contrario sensu"

That question mark represents a position increment, in this case a removed stop word. So it's looking for the phrase with a gap where a stop word has been removed at the beginning.

You can disable position increments in the query parser with `QueryParser.setEnablePositionIncrements(false)`, though you should be aware this could cause problems for you if you still have position increments in the index, and run into a stop word in the middle of a phrase.

Comment: Printing the query after parsing show  Rubro:"a contrario sensu" so at least in that moment the stop word has not been removed. I also set to false the position increments but nothing change at all

Comment: @danilo_zac - Well, you don't show how you define your analyzer, so all I can do it take your word for it. Are you giving it an empty stop set or some such?

Comment: I'm just doing something like this to define the analyzer Analyzer analyzer = new StandarAnalyzer();

Comment: Wait a minute... Taking a closer look, you aren't actually using that QueryParser you constructed. A manually constructed `PhraseQuery` isn't going to do any analysis, which means, of course, that it won't eliminate stop words. If you want to construct the PhraseQuery yourself, you have to handle any analysis concerns first.

Comment: I take the approach of the PhraseQuery cause using the QueryParse looks for every word separately, not for the complete phrase, printing the parsing shows Rubro:contrario Rubro: sensu in this case the analyzer is taking away the stop word

Comment: @danilo_zav - Use quotation marks for a phrase query. You can read the [query parser syntax documentation here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html).

Comment: At the end and after taking different approaches, each of them giving the same or worst results i solve this issue defining my own array of stoppers and passing it to the analyzer like this Analyzer analyzer = new StandarAnalyzer(new string[]{ "Example", "Example1"}  I don´t thing this is the best approach but works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The StandardAnalyzer will exclude a set of *stop words* including "a" (see the end of https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/blob/3.0.3-2/src/core/Analysis/StopAnalyzer.cs for a full list)

It is important that the analysis style when querying is compatible with the style used when indexing. This is why your PhraseQuery only works *without* the "a" because the indexing step removed it.

You can use the StandardAnalyzer ctor that takes `ISet<string> stopWords` and pass in `new HashSet<string>()` Something like:

```
new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30, new HashSet<string>())
```

This means that *all* words will be included in the token stream for the field.

Use this analyzer when indexing and querying and you will get better results.

However, you should note that the StandardAnalyzer also fiddles with the words somewhat. It is designed to be "a good tokenizer for most European-language documents". See the comments at the beginning of https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/blob/3.0.3-2/src/core/Analysis/Standard/StandardTokenizer.cs for some more info and check if it's compatible with your use case.

It may be worth your time to investigate different analyzers for the kind of text you are indexing.